# java.langIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, exception

```
 if( (i<1 || i>gridSize) || ( j<1 || j>gridSize ) )
     throw new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException ;
```

This is a snippet of code from the program I am writing in which ( this is an excercise ) we are asked to throw `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index `i` is out of the grid . But when I compile it shows the following error . 
3 errors found:

```
File: C:\Users\das\Desktop\Percolation.java  [line: 19]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

How can I correct it ?

Comment: note: zero is inside the array, if this is true for your case, then change the check to i < 0 || i > gridSize

Comment: yeah I know that I had declared a N+1 by N+1 array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it needs constructing like any normal object

```
throw new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException ();
```

Comment: thanks this is my first java program , sorry if the question was too simple

Answer (score 3):

[java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is a class. When you are going to throw an exception, you need to build an exception class instance, so you need to do:

```
new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

when the class instance has built then you can throw it via `throw` command and the full command looks like that:

```
throw new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

when you forgot to type `()` compiler detected incorrect constructor invokation and reported it.

Hope it will help to understand what is going on, and good luck with java. It is a great language.